# Postgres 9.6, timezones: why are those two queries giving me different times

Tags: postgresql, timezone, utc

Ok so I've always been fuzzy with the timezones. I'm getting better, but not there yet. Can you people enlighten me?

Context: I receive a UTC time from the frontend. For example, to denote the date `1 September 2019`, I'll get `2019-08-31 22:00:00Z` (we're in Brussels DST, hence the 2 hours difference).

From that date, I need to generate a series of 6 months before that. So that's `March April May June July August`.

I managed to find a solution, somewhat out of luck to be honest. I'm still not sure I understand the details of what happens below:

```
database=> show timezone;
 TimeZone 
----------
 UTC
(1 row)

database=> select generate_series(
        ('2019-08-31 22:00:00Z'::timestamp at time zone 'Europe/Brussels')::date - '6 month'::interval,
        ('2019-08-31 22:00:00Z'::timestamp at time zone 'Europe/Brussels')::date - '1 month'::interval,
        '1 month'::interval
      );
   generate_series   
---------------------
 2019-02-28 00:00:00
 2019-03-28 00:00:00
 2019-04-28 00:00:00
 2019-05-28 00:00:00
 2019-06-28 00:00:00
 2019-07-28 00:00:00
(6 rows)

database=> select generate_series(
        ('2019-08-31 22:00:00Z' at time zone 'Europe/Brussels')::date - '6 month'::interval,
        ('2019-08-31 22:00:00Z' at time zone 'Europe/Brussels')::date - '1 month'::interval,
        '1 month'::interval
      );
   generate_series   
---------------------
 2019-03-01 00:00:00
 2019-04-01 00:00:00
 2019-05-01 00:00:00
 2019-06-01 00:00:00
 2019-07-01 00:00:00
 2019-08-01 00:00:00
```

Why do I get wrong results if I use `::timestamp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually two different &ldauo;operators” named `AT TIME ZONE`, one converting `timestamp with time zone` to `timestamp without time zone` and one the other way around.

If the first argument is a `timestamp with time zone`, the value is converted to a `timestamp without time zone` that shows what a wall clock in that time zone would.

If the first argument is a `timestamp without time zone`, it is interpreted in the session time zone (given by the value of the `timezone` parameter) and converted to an absolute time stamp.

Now `timestamp with time zone` is the *preferred type* of the date/time *type category*, so the string literal in your second query is interpreted as a `timestamp with time zone` in accordance with [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-oper.html). In the first query it is a `timestamp without time zone`. Since there are different operators involved, it is not surprising that the results are different.

In your first query, the wall clock time 22:00 is interpreted as if the clock hung in Brussels, so it is actually 20:00 UTC. The first argument of `generate_series`, from which counting starts, is then Feb 28 2019, 20:00 UTC (before casting to `date`).